# Function from closed set to closed set - both true and not true?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions

Consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f((s,t))=2s$. Is it true or not that $f$ maps closed sets to closed sets? I thought that it is not true, because we could consider the set $A:=\{(s,0)\in \mathbb{R}^2:s\in \mathbb{R}\}$, which is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then $f(A)=(-\infty,\infty)$, which is open in $\mathbb{R}$. However, $f(A)$ is also closed in $\mathbb{R}$.

So, from the logic standpoint, can we say that this is a counterexample, or not? Or can we say that this example can be both true and false?

Comment: $\mathbb R $ is also closed.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima Yes, but the point is that it's also open, so we can actually view it as an open set.

Comment: A few sets are both open and closed.  So your example maps a closed set to a closed set.  It also maps that closed set to an open set.  No contradiction, as the set $(-\infty, +\infty)$ is both open and closed.  Now... can you find a different closed set $B$ where $f(B)$ is not closed?

Comment: @sequence The thing is that "viewing it" as open isn't in contradiction to it being closed. It's not viewed as one or the other, it's simply both.

Comment: An actual counterexample would be when $A := \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : xy = 1 \}$, which is closed but the image is $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\mathbb{R}$ is closed and open. This is not a matter of logic, but a matter of terminology. "Closed" and "open" are logically independent from each other: "closed" doesn't mean "not open", nor does "open" mean "not closed".

For the set you described $A$, you correctly understood that $A$ is closed and that $f(A)$ is open and closed. Since $f(A)$ is closed, $f$ maps this particular closed set to a closed set. So it is not a counterexample. Now, the question you have to answer is: does $f$ map *all* closed sets to closed sets?

Answer (score 4):

A counterexample would consist of a closed set whose image is not closed. Open and closed are not opposites (despite what might be inferred from the name). Indeed, you've noted that $\mathbb{R}$ is both open and closed.

Thus this is not a counterexample at all.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, your $A$ is not a counterexample. But the set $A = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: xy= 1\}$ is closed in the plane (it's a set of the form $q^{-1}[\{1\}]$ for $q(x,y) = xy$). But $f[A] = \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, which is *not* closed (as $0$ is its closure but not in the set, or because $\{0\}$ is not open).

To see that $f[A] = \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$: let $f(s,t) \in f[A]$ , so $(s,t) \in A$. Then $s \neq 0$ (otherwise $(s,t) \notin A$), so $f(s,t) = 2s \neq 0$ as well. And if $y \neq 0$ is a real number, $x:= (\frac{y}{2}, \frac{2}{y}) \in A$ and $f(x) = y$.